# Wildfly Undertow stop responding

Tags: linux, wildfly, undertow

Recently widlfy undertow in production stop to response.

the ejb timers continue to works correctly and the widfly service is up, but each web module stop to responding.

It happened different times (one or two each day) In the server.log there are not same indications about the reason:

One time server.log reports too many file descriptor opened on socket exception, but next time when happend again other reason:

..completed with multiple threads - thread default task-135 was in progress with java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method).

when problem occurs

lsof -f | wc -l

count is 6000

netstat -anp | grep -w 80 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l

count 15 on port 80

count 191 on port 443

Wildfly version 10.1.0

the undertow version in

/opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/io/undertow/core/main/

is 1.4.0

How can I debug the problem? there are some setup on wildfly to got details about server status (http connection, jndi, ram used etc)?

Can I collect other details at linux os level?